# Upload timeout issue FTP Clients in windows 8.1

Tags: ftp, windows-8.1

I am getting timeout issue with upload file via FTP clients in windows 8.1. I have used filezilla client and fireFTP also. I am getting this issue apx all connections. I have tried to upload with many server.

Filezilla log error -

Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  File transfer failed

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you've solved your problem over the past few months, but I ran across a very similar issue with a new Win 8.1 box and found that my router settings were to blame. I needed to adjust my router firewall to a lower security setting to allow the FTP traffic to flow properly.

Also, I set the mode of my FTP connections to "passive" ... I had been using "active" per several articles and posts that outlined related issues with FTP and Win 8.1 and this apparently was not working in combination with the router settings.

Comment: I have no idea. I have changed my internet provider and fixed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue it due to IE 11 in Windows 8.1. Please use core FTP to solve this problem.